# Get list of users in a role with SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

So what I am trying to accomplish is that when a user sends a message, on the server-side I would like to know which "other" connections are available. I am using SignalR.

From those connections, I would like to know the roles of the users associated with each connection.

I am using ASP.NET Identity, SignalR, and C#.

Then I would like to filter out the connections based on user roles and broadcast a message to only those users.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to do that

Basically you can send the token from client to server (JWT in this case). JWT can contain all information you need.

> The access token function you provide is called before every HTTP
>   request made by SignalR. If you need to renew the token in order to
>   keep the connection active (because it may expire during the
>   connection), do so from within this function and return the updated
>   token.

So that mean when ever user call signalr they will be authenticate again in the hub.

Or you can add claim to the user so you can detect who request and what role do they have

Sample from the document:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            // Identity made Cookie authentication the default.
            // However, we want JWT Bearer Auth to be the default.
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            // Configure JWT Bearer Auth to expect our security key
            options.TokenValidationParameters =
                new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    LifetimeValidator = (before, expires, token, param) =>
                    {
                        return expires > DateTime.UtcNow;
                    },
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateActor = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKey
                };

            // We have to hook the OnMessageReceived event in order to
            // allow the JWT authentication handler to read the access
            // token from the query string when a WebSocket or 
            // Server-Sent Events request comes in.
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                    // If the request is for our hub...
                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                        (path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs/chat")))
                    {
                        // Read the token out of the query string
                        context.Token = accessToken;
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddSignalR();

    // Change to use Name as the user identifier for SignalR
    // WARNING: This requires that the source of your JWT token 
    // ensures that the Name claim is unique!
    // If the Name claim isn't unique, users could receive messages 
    // intended for a different user!
    services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();

    // Change to use email as the user identifier for SignalR
    // services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, EmailBasedUserIdProvider>();

    // WARNING: use *either* the NameUserIdProvider *or* the 
    // EmailBasedUserIdProvider, but do not use both. 
}
```